# Is it possible for a Matlab function to return vectors?

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, vector

I'm writing a Matlab program that calculates supersonic flow following the McCormack solution. I want to split the code into parts to make it easier to read and find errors. I would like to use functions in my code, but for this we must use 8 vectors and I don't know if it's possible for the function to loop the calculation in the space and at the same time return the vectors. In the current state of the code, it is done by a simple series of loops.

I wish to be something like

```
function [F(1,i,j) F(2,i,j)...] = governing_equations(rho,v,u...)
```

Is this possible?

Now it works as indicated in the books, using a loop in space and calculating the points in the grid (i and j)

```
for i=1:1:M
   for j=1:1:N
    
    F(1,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j);
    F(2,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(u(i,j)^2)+p(i,j);
    F(3,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*v(i,j);
    F(4,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*(e(i,j)+((V(i,j)^2)/2))+p(i,j)*u(i,j);
    
    G(1,i,j)=rho(i,j)*v(i,j);
    G(2,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*v(i,j);
    G(3,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(v(i,j)^2)+p(i,j);
    G(4,i,j)=rho(i,j)*v(i,j)*(e(i,j)+((V(i,j)^2)/2))+p(i,j)*v(i,j);

   end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with `function [F, G] = governing_equations(rho, v, u)`?

Comment: Also note it'll run much faster without the loops: `F(1,:,:) = rho.*u`

Comment: I’m unsure what the question is. Which part do you want to separate out into a function?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to write formulas in a concise way MATLAB has certain advantages compared to many coding languages.

**1.- Highly possible no need for these 2 FOR loops**

Since you have not shown anything but these 2 `for` loops, at least by they way you have put it, in MATLAB both may be avoided :

I repeat it's highly likely that there's **NO NEED** for

```
for i=1:1:M
for j=1:1:N 
..

end
end
```

Just do the following

**2.-** Make sure wherever you have defined `rho` and `u` with the **right sizes** so their product does not return size mismatch

```
[sz1 sz2]=size(rho);
[sz3 sz4]=size(u);

sz1==sz4

sz2==sz3
```

are both true.

**3.- Define `F`**

```
F=zeros(sz1,sz1,4)
```

Now, instead of

```
F(1,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j);
```

do

```
F=(:,:,1)=rho*u
```

if `prod(size(rho)==size(u))>0` meaning `rho` and `u` have all sizes equal values, perhaps you have to do **element-to-element** product,

F=(:,:,1)=rho.*u

instead of

```
F(2,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(u(i,j)^2)+p(i,j);
```

do

```
F(:,:,2)=rho.*(u.^2)+p;
```

or

```
F(:,:,2)=rho*(u.^2)+p;
```

Instead of

```
F(3,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*v(i,j);
```

do

```
F(:,:,4)=rho.*u.*v;
```

or

```
F(:,:,4)=rho*u*v;
```

if all sizes allow it

Instead of

```
F(4,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*(e(i,j)+((V(i,j)^2)/2))+p(i,j)*u(i,j);
```

do

```
F(:,:,4)=rho.*u.*(e+((V.^2)/2))+p.*u;
```

or simply

```
F(:,:,4)=rho*u*(e+((V.^2)/2))+p*u;
```

if all sizes allow it.